# Drag and Drop item sobre componentes

Tags: css, drag-n-drop

Estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade drag and drop de um menu lateral para uma lista.

Tenho 2 problemas:

1 - Quando eu arrasto o item do menu lateral, o item é mostrado somente sobre o menu, quando eu movo o mouse para fora do menu ele não e mostrado (Examplo na imagem 2)

- Sei que é algo relacionado com o z-index mas não estou conseguindo aplicar.

2 - Eu consegui arrastar um item e atribuir na lista quando eu estava testando no developer tools, mas agora não está funcionando e estou ralando pra descobrir qual a propriedade que eu alterei, acredito que a "position".

Gostaria que me ajudassem a setar essas propriedades e se estou certo em relação ao z-index e ao position.

Obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Quando eu arrasto o item do menu lateral, o item é mostrado somente sobre o menu, quando eu movo o mouse para fora do menu ele não e mostrado (Examplo na imagem 2)

R-

```
.sidebar-container {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

2 - Eu consegui arrastar um item e atribuir na lista quando eu estava testando no developer tools, mas agora não está funcionando e estou ralando pra descobrir qual a propriedade que eu alterei, acredito que a "position".

R - Estava com javascript duplicado na tela, não sei qual a influência que estava tendo mas resolveu quando removi.